# How to use hash function in java for hashing the password?

Tags: java

I am trying to hash a password and save it in the database; I know hashing is a one way process. How can I check whether the user supplied password and the one stored in the database are same? I am using MD5 and I am getting different values for the same input when I perform hashing each time. Can anyone help?

```
String pass = "wor1ldcup";
    String pass1 = "wor1ldcup";

    DigestUtils du = new DigestUtils();
    byte[] b = du.md5(pass);
    byte[] b1 = du.md5(pass1);
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of the faulty code you're using to generate defferent md5 values from the same input?

Comment: I am able to hash the value but i dont know how use the value again for comparison

Comment: /agree with Yanick. If you're using MD5 right, it won't change unless the input changes. That's why it's used so much for validation (not that it's not possible to break it, because it is, but...)

Comment: This is not a dupe i am able to hash the string but dont know how to use the hashed value. please read the question properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you supplied is basically correct, with a couple of caveats:

1. The methods of `DigestUtils` are all `static`, and hence should be invoked as:

   ```
   byte[] b = DigestUtils.md5(...);
   ```

   and not as

   ```
   DigestUtils du = new DigestUtils();  // wrong ... no need to instantiate
   byte[] b = du.md5(...);              // wrong ... never use an instance to
                                        //           call a static method.
   ```
2. You don't show how you compare the `b` and `b1`, but `b == b1` won't work, and neither will `b.equals(b2)` ... both compare references.  You need to call `Arrays.equals(b, b1)`.
3. It is a **bad idea** to try to turn an MD5 hash into a String.  Depending on the default character set, the conversion may turn out to be lossy; i.e. not reversible.  If you want to store an MD5 hash in a database, it is better to encode as a String using (for example) base64 encoding, and save the encoded hash.

Comment: +1 for the "bad idea". Hashed data should always be treated as an opaque blob and you should only turn it into a `String` if you absolutely have to. Same goes for encrypted data.

Comment: Thank you very much if u have any tutorials regarding hashing please post it...You have mentioned about character set conversion and base64 encoding i have no idea about it please help

Answer (score 3):

You really should use bcrypt instead of MD5 for password storage.  [Here is an article on why](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) (there are many more).

The [jBcrypt library](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) works well.

Comment: +1 my first thought and I was going to comment that... That said your answer should have been a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import java.security.*;

byte[] password;
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
messageDigest.update(password, 0, password.length);
byte[] passwordHashed = messageDigest.digest();
```

Need to convert `String` to `byte[]` and `byte[]` to hex or Base64 `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things to check:

- Are you comparing the hashes in the same case? i.e. are the alphabetic digits in the hashes in lowercase in both versions?
- Is it possible that a leading 0 has been truncated from the front of one of the hashes?
- Are you comparing two Strings using == ? Use .equals instead.

If all of those are ok, the hashing should return the same value each time for the exact same input.

Comment: see the above code If i print b and b1 its showing different values.

Comment: Ah, didn't see the code. Oh well, Stephen's answer looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

At the most basic level, when using a hashing function for passwords you hash the password when initially storing it and then hash any attempts to match that original.

So, when you are trying to validate a password for an existing user your basic query would use the hashed version of the submitted password as a parameter.

```
SELECT * FROM Users where ID = 1234 and Password = @Password
```

binding @Password to du.md5(submittedPassword)